# Azure Automation Runbook with azure-resourcemanager-automation java

Tags: java, sdk, azure-automation

I already have a runbook in Azure with several jobs attached to it. These have all been created via Azure.

Now I want to use the Java SDK for future jobs, I know that the azure-resourcemanager-automation is still in beta, but maybe someone can help me.

I can already create the schedules and they end up in my automation account.

What I can't manage is to link these schedules with my runbook and to fill the variables of the runbook, so that a job is executed according to the schedule.

```
AutomationClient.getSchedules().createOrUpdate()
```

How can I link this Schedules to my Runbook and set the 5 Runbook parameter?

The documentation is still quite thin due to the beta status.

[Azure Automation Doku](https://azuresdkdocs.blob.core.windows.net/$web/java/azure-resourcemanager-automation/1.0.0-beta.1/index.html)

Answer (score 0):

**Update**

I have found a solution:

first we need a JobScheduleCreateParameter, here we link all together

```
new JobScheduleCreateParameters().withRunbook("runbookName").withSchedule("scheduleName").withParameters(paramMap)
```

and then we can create the Job

```
new AutomationClient().getJobSchedules().create("resourceGroup", "automationAccount", UUID.randomUUID(), jobscheduleCreateParameter);
```